# Calling data values from controller to view in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to get my page to display a sum of costs but I'm having problems trying to call the variable form my controller. Below is my code:

Controller:

```
public function cost()
{
    $data['training'] = $this->form_model->getStatistics();
    $data['cost'] = $this->form_model->getTotalCost();
    $this->load->view('costStats_view', $data);
}
```

Model:

```
function getTotalCost()
 {
      $query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(cost) AS totalCost FROM tbl_training");
      return $query->result();
 }
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label>Tota Cost</label>  
     <p class="form-control-static"><?=$cost['totalCost'];?></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[result()](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html)**

> This method returns the query result as an array of objects, or an
>   empty array on failure. Typically you’ll use this in a foreach loop

**views**

```
<?php
    foreach ($cost as $row)
    {
?>
            <p class="form-control-static"><?=$row->totalCost;?></p>
<?php 
    }
?>
```